# Is there a significant loss in a voltage doubler circuit?

Tags: capacitor, generator, alternator

I am making a small generator just for experimentation.

I need to double the voltage that the generator coils are producing.

But I can't just connect them in series, because they are out of phase with each other.

So the plan is simple; 1 gen coil charges 1 capacitor, another generator coil charges another capacitor and I connect the capacitors in series.

But I read that capacitors in series cut the capacity by half.

That means that my gen coils are going to produce half the amperage? or not?

Comment: Can't you reverse one of the generator coils then they are in series. Also, it sounds like you are generating AC and without steering diodes and active switches your capacitor idea won't work.

Comment: It would be complicated to move the coil, and yes of course I would need some diodes, don't know what you mean about the switches...

Comment: It sounds like your generator is producing alternating current. In that case you could use a transformer to step the voltage up. If you double the voltage with a transformer you will get half the current. Perhaps a picture or diagram of your generator setup would help us give better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your generating apparatus is producing AC, it's easy to build a charge pump using diodes and capacitors; a voltage doubler is the most common form, but it's possible to build higher multiples as well.  The steady-state current drawn from the generator will be doubled but the voltage will be somewhat less than double.  Some of the loss will be in the diodes, but some will also occur because capacitors will be called upon to supply current continuously but are filled intermittently.  Consequently, by the time one capacitor reaches maximum voltage, the other capacitor will have sagged somewhat from its maximum.

Comment: I understand, tnx supercat

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not a simple plan at all, unless you're disconnecting the capacitors and using them like batteries. It sounds like you want to do three things:

1. Connect each generator coil to one capacitor.
2. Connect the two capacitors to each other in series.
3. Not connect the generator coils to each other.

You can't do that all at once. You can use a switching circuit to alternate between the two states, but that's unlikely to give a good voltage doubler.

I suspect the best solution to this is to either make your generator produce a higher voltage, or use a boost converter. The boost converter can be fed from both coils by using diodes.